# Writing Cocoa applications in Python 3

Tags: python, cocoa, python-3.x, pyobjc

It looks like PyObjC is not ported to Python 3 yet.

Meanwhile is there a way to write Cocoa applications using Python 3?

I am intending to start a new MacOSX GUI application project and though5 would want to use Python 3.x instead of Python 2.x.

Answer (score 3):

For full-blown Cocoa, I think PyObjC is pretty much the only game in town.  If you are coming to Cocoa from a Python background rather than to Python from an Obj-C Cocoa background, surely the learning curve of the Cocoa APIs is *much* steeper than the differences between Python 2.x and Python 3.x.  So I think, at the moment, the best strategy is writing your app in Python 2.x while trying to make it as Python 3.x friendly as possible, including periodically running [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) on it as a check.  And I'm sure [patches for PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/development.html) to help with Python 3 support would be very welcome.  If you are just looking for simple GUI interfaces rather than a full-blown Cocoa app, you *might* be able to get by with calls out to other packages like [CocoaDialog](http://cocoadialog.sourceforge.net/) or a Python 2.x-PyObjC dialog app :=)