# 502 Bad Gateway in GAE with Django, & Log say "libBLT.2.5.so.8.6 No such file or directory"

Tags: python, django, nginx, tkinter, google-app-engine

- Django 4.0.4
- Python 3.8.9

I deployed Django App to GAE.
But I got "502 Bad Gateway" error. And I checked server logs. That is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
   worker.init_process()
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
   self.load_wsgi()
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
   self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
   self.callable = self.load()
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
   return self.load_wsgiapp()
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
   return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
   mod = importlib.import_module(module)
 File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "/workspace/SakeMarksV1/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
   application = get_wsgi_application()
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
   django.setup(set_prefix=False)
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
   apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
   app_config.import_models()
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
   self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
 File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "/workspace/website/models.py", line 1, in <module>
   import turtledemo.nim
 File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/turtledemo/nim.py", line 13, in <module>
   import turtle
 File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
   import tkinter as TK
 File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
   import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libBLT.2.5.so.8.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm thinking that GAE instance has no TK or gunicorn is not working.
Do anyone know about this kind of problem?
Thank you.

-- app.yaml --

```
runtime: python38

instance_class: F1

env: standard

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT <PROJECT_NAME>.wsgi:application

includes:
    - secret.yaml

handlers:
    - url: /static
      static_dir: static/
    - url: /.*
      script: auto
      secure: always

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2
```

-- settings/base.py --

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'website.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'website',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'social_django',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_cleanup',
    'stdimage',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

ROOT_URLCONF = '<PROJECT_NAME>.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = '<PROJECT_NAME>.wsgi.application'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

PROJECT_NAME = os.path.basename(BASE_DIR)

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = f'var/www/{PROJECT_NAME}/static'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

-- settings/production.py --

```
from .base import *

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<CUSTOM_DOMAIN>']

# データベース
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/' + os.getenv('DB_CONNECTION_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
    }
}


# ストレージ
from google.oauth2 import service_account
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<PROJECT_NAME>/settings/<CREDENTIAL_FILE>.json')
)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'

GS_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('GS_BUCKET_NAME')
GS_PROJECT_ID = '<PROJECT_NAME>'

# ソーシャルログイン
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = os.getenv('SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY')
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = os.getenv('SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET')

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = os.getenv('SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY')
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = os.getenv('SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET')
```

Comment: tkinter does not work on app engine and it doesn't work in a web browser anyway.  I don't know what turtle is but you can try using parts of turtle that don't depend on tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself.
There was the code `import turtledemo` on `views.py` and the library needs TK. That was the cause of the error.
PyCharm automatically added this code.
Thank you, Supun Kaihara and NoCommandLine.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Change your entrypoint to just

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT <PROJECT_NAME>.wsgi
```

<s>Since you have an `entrypoint` in your `app.yaml` file which is run via `gunicorn`, you must explicitly include `gunicorn` in `requirements.txt` file</s>

Comment: Thank you. I include ```gunicorn ``` in my ```requirements.txt```. But I'm getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

Like you mentioned, the error might be from tkinter, try this:

[Deploy keras model to google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71915339/16425641)

Comment: This might not be the exact answer as I wasn't able to pin point the error either but I can't comment yet so sorry about that, hope this helps.

Comment: It should be in the file where you wrote code for tkinter. I read more on this and it seems its not recommended to use tkinter for any web browser rendering. Could you explain your application structure a bit more?

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Django for my application. So I don't need to write any code about tkinter and I have no code like that.